# CNAME links to WordPress blog but redirects cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, cname

I've got IIS hosting site(www.site2.com) and wanted to add wordpress blog site on this website, but wordpress is PHP based so I used a tricky way. 
I've got PHP hosting site(www.site1.com) so set up self-hosted wordpress blog on this site then adding CNAME on site2.com domain, I believed it should work.

So, installed wordpress in PHP hosting site(cpanel hosting) and create blog site on this wordpress, the url is www.site1.com/blogb. Then created subdomain from cpanel(blogb.site1.com) which linked to www.site1.com/blogb as root folder.
When I go to blogb.site1.com, it's working so good.

One last thing what I did is adding CNAME from site2 zone manager.

blog.site2.com -> blogb.site1.com

I think this should work because blogb.site1.com is working properly.
But when I go to blog.site2.com, redirected to "/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi" page then showed "SORRY ... If you are the owner of this website, please contact your hosting provider" message.

I cleared cache from my browner and tried from other browser but didn't work.
And added rewrite rule on .htaccess file on site1.com root folder but nothing worth.

I checked site URL from wordpress settings page, the site address(URL) was "blogb.site1.com" which was correct.

I believe if destination url of CNAME is working, the CNAME should work.

But when I try to access a file in destination folder using this url,  blog.site2.com/readme.html, returns 404 not found while blogb.site1.com/readme.html is working.

So, CNAME(blog.site2.com) seems be pointing wrong directory.

Is there anything I missed or did wrong?

Thank you,

B